# How to pass the values fetched in a variable to another variable

Tags: python-3.x

I have written the below code to get the values in agent_name and now I want to pass individual values to another variable to get other data. How can I do that?

**Code**

```
for x in range(len(json_data)):
    agent_name=json_data[x]['name']
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "pass individual values to another variable to get other data" part?

Comment: okay so now the values i am getting in agent_name , i want to pass to below api and get values -> agentName_api = 'https://deploy-dev.cisco.com:8443/cli/agentCLI/info?agent='+agent_name   . Basically i want to store the values of the above for loop as array and I am not able to do it .